# Running SQL Query on remote vs local MySQL server

Tags: mysql

I am able to execute following query in remote MySQL server but when running it from local MySQL server, I am getting the following error.

Query:

```
select
    y.school_grade
    , y.gender
    , count(1)
from
    (
    select
        x.*
    from
        (
        select
            sc.student_id
            , s.gender
            , s.school_grade
            , o.category_id
        from
            student_class sc
        left join student s on
            sc.student_id = s.student_id
        left join student_history h on
            h.student_id = s.student_id
        left join class c on
            c.class_id = sc.class_id_id
        left join category o on
            o.category_id = c.category_id_id
        where 
            s.is_active = 1
            and h.payment_complete = 1
            and month(s.created_date) >= 7
            and year(s.created_date) >= 2023
        order by
            s.school_grade
            , s.gender
) 
as x
    group by
        x.student_id
    having
        count(1) = 1
)
as y
where
    y.category_id = 1
group by
    y.school_grade
    , y.gender
order by
    y.school_grade
    , y.gender desc;
```

Django:

```
>>> query1 = r"<query above>"
>>> with connection.cursor() as cursor:
...  cursor.execute(query1)
...  rows_all = cursor.fetchall()
```

Error:

django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1055, "1055 (42000): Expression #4 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'x.category_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by", '42000')

Observations:

- I can execute the query on a remote server
- I can not execute the query on local server

Question:

1. How can I find the root cause of this behavior?
2. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

it's because the `only_full_group_by` is enabled on your local MySQL server!
so check SQL mode first and look for `only_full_group_by` in the result, to do this write like below :

```
SELECT @@sql_mode;
```

now you can compare your SQL mode settings between your local MySQL server and the remote MySQL server, if `only_full_group_by` is enabled on your local server but disabled on the remote server, that explains the difference in behavior!

you can also edit your MySQL settings in your Django project's settings file `settings.py`,to do this set the `OPTIONS` dictionary for the MySQL database configuration to include `'sql_mode':

```
STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
```